# C++ constructor delegation, but how to (sort of) invert?

Tags: c++, constructor, delegating-constructor

I understand that in C++11 constructor delegation can looks like this:

```
class Foo
{
 public:
  Foo()
   {
     // Some code to be ran first
   }
  Foo(std::string bar): Foo() // Runs the code to be ran first
   {
    // Some code to be ran second, presumably using bar
   }
};
```

I want to know how to invert this situation, in a way.  Namely, in the case the `Foo()` constructor is called, I want to run some code to figure out a value for a `std::string` that would then be used by `Foo(std::string bar)` to finish initialization.  So `Foo()` runs both its own code and the code in `Foo(std::string bar)`, while the the latter runs only its own code, something like

```
class Foo
{
 public:
  Foo()
   {
     std::string bar_figured_out;
     // Figures out the value for bar_figured_out

     Foo(bar_figured_out); // I know this wouldn't work, just an example of what I'm trying to do.
   }
  Foo(std::string bar):
   {
    // Some code to finish class initialization, using bar
   }
};
```

Is there any way to accomplish this using constructor delegation?

Comment: @uneven_mark, my intention is to not make `bar_figured_out` a class member if possible.  But regardless, I cannot run `Foo()`'s code if `Foo(std::string bar)` is given, since the code in `Foo()` may fail to determine `bar_figured_out` in certain situations, but in cases where `Foo` is given `bar` it should not have to fail over not finding something it won't even be using.

Comment: I think I misunderstood you originally.  @HolyBlackCat's answer seems appropriate, if I understand correctly now.

Comment: Because you have the solution in the answer, you can exploit a bit more c++11 characteristics using lambda functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options:

- Move the code from `Foo(std::string bar)` to a member function, and call it from both `Foo()` and `Foo(std::string bar)`.
- Move the code that determines the value of `bar_figured_out` to a member function, and then have `Foo()` call that function when delegating to `Foo(std::string bar)`:

  ```
  Foo() : Foo(compute_bar()) {}
  ```